# Am I using the right way to test a storage device's read/write speed?

Tags: c#, windows

I am new to this area so sorry if the question is stupid.

So far I have written a program that tests a storage device (USB, SD card, HDD, SSD....) reading and writing speed by C#.

The way I get the speed is by getting the time it writes an LBA or a file (dependent it has a partition or not)

Code is something like

```
StartTime = DataTime.Now;
WriteLBA(LBAsize);
EndTime = DataTime.Now;
```

(I'm using win32 libery Kernel)

I have two questions:

**I got a different result by using another software like HD tune**

usually, the speed I got from my program is too fast both read and write.
However, if I change the LBA/file Size the read and write speed change.
So, here is my second question:

**What is the LBA/file size should I set?**

It seems like different devices or even storage capacity have different influences.

At the end of this, I can't help myself but thinking I may use the wrong way to test it?

Comment: You are certainly using the wrong tool. Writing a benchmark using a platform with unpredictable performance characteristics is a poor choice. Either use a programming language and platform with deterministic garbage collection, or one where you have enough control over the non-deterministic garbage collector to gather reliable results.

Comment: So you're saying, I'm using the wrong language to do it? What are the chooses other than C#?

Comment: I'm not saying that you're using the wrong language. I'm saying that you're targeting an inappropriate platform (the .NET CLR). C, for example, gets you much more predictability.

Comment: I see. So there is a better way to do it in C?